# PC won't wake up from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power, hibernate

The OS is Windows 10 with hibernation completely disabled through command line. Yet, the PC still won't wake up from sleep when *Wake History Count* more than 0.

When my computer goes to sleep for the first time since it was started, the led light on the tower is blinking and it wakes up perfectly upon mouse move or any key press. However, when the computer goes to sleep for the second time, the led indicator goes off and PC does not react to the keyboard or mouse. When I press power button the led light goes on, and fans start, but PC still won't wake up, neither by keyboard/mouse, nor power button press. I have to unplug it for some time in order to turn it on.

Here's the *wake_armed* command result:

```
$ powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
HID Keyboard Device
NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller
HID-compliant mouse
```

Here's power settings:

[image]

EDIT:

Here's the result of *powercfg /energy* test:

[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly this was a bug with earlier versions of Win10; are you up to date?

Comment: Yes, all updates are being checked on a daily basis, my windows appears to be up to date.

Comment: Open your command prompt and type "winver", then give us the Version and OS Build from the dialog that comes up. This will help us confirm whether you're fully up-to-date.

Comment: Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.250)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the BIOS and fireware from the device manufacturer website for the latest Windows 10 compatible drivers.

Run the built-in troubleshooter tool to have a diagnostic.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\All Categories\Power

Open an administrator command line and run "powercfg /energy" for more information to troubleshoot this issue. Pay attention to the errors and warnings.

Comment: I've updated my question to include errors from "powercfg /energy" test. I'm not sure what they mean though. Working on updating BIOS...

Comment: I've updated my AMI BIOS to the latest version (1.60 > 1.80) I could find at my ASRock motherboard website, but the problem still persists: the PC wakes up from the first time sleep normally, but from the second sleep it does not wake up, I have to unplug it for several seconds and plug it back in to be able to turn the PC on.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I went through so many permutations before I finally found it to be a faulty psu (can also happen if not powerful enough). Swapped out and waking from sleep problems dissipated